# How can I get current date + 4 HOURS in a SQL Statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to retrieve data from a a table, between YESTERDAY (starting at 4am) and TODAY (ending at 4am). What is the best way to go about automating this? I am thinking perhaps grab today's date and offsetting 4 hours and assign it to a variable? Currently manually entering the time/date each day.

Current code:

```
SELECT "HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA"."iReportDataID"
FROM   "WinTest1"."dbo"."HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA" "HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA"
WHERE  ("HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA"."dtTime">={ts '2011-10-19 04:00:00'} AND"HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA"."dtTime"<{ts '2011-10-20 04:00:00'})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What RDBMS?  SQL Server?  What version?

Comment: The tsql tag limits us to Sybase / SQL Server

Comment: I realize that, but versions are important.

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @HOURS_OFFSET INT=4; -- 4 AM

DECLARE @YESTERDAY_WITH_OFFSET DATETIME=DATEADD(hh, @HOURS_OFFSET, DATEADD(dd, -1, 
                                  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)));
DECLARE @TODAY_WITH_OFFSET DATETIME=DATEADD(hh, @HOURS_OFFSET,DATEADD(dd, 
                                      DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0));

SELECT HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA.iReportDataID 
FROM   WinTest1.dbo.HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA AS HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA 
WHERE  HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA.dtTime >= @YESTERDAY_WITH_OFFSET 
   AND HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA.dtTime <= @TODAY_WITH_OFFSET
```

Comment: I just need to adjust the code to format date/time as 2011-10-19 04:00:00, otherwise works well. Thank you.

**EDIT:** Spoke too soon, sorry, just realized that the date formatting has no effect on the search itself in this way. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

[dateadd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) will do what your title asks:

For example:
`select getdate(), dateadd(hh, 4, getdate())`

However, you can filter by date range using `between`, no need for variables:

For example:

```
SELECT  HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA.iReportDataID
FROM    WinTest1..HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA
WHERE   HC_PRIME_REPORTDATA.dtTime between dateadd(hh, 4, convert(datetime, convert(date, dateadd(d, -1, getdate()))))
                                            and dateadd(hh, 4, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))
```

Comment: He wants to make it 4am, this will return current time +4 hours.

Comment: @JNK `convert`ing to date will lose the time component, essentially making it midnight. Then the `dateadd` increases that to 4am

Comment: 1 - You just added that in the edit.  2 - You are assuming SQL Server 2008+

Comment: @JNK that's why I initially qualified the `dateadd` segment, since his title and actual question are two different things. Furthermore, the OP is asking about 2008 so my answer is entirely valid.